# Android 9.0 not showing SSID - Chrysler Uconnect

Tags: 9.0-pie

Recently I bought a Chrysler Pacifica 2019 which has Uconnect 8.4 and built in WiFi. I also bought couple android 9.0 headrest monitor. When I am trying to connect the android devices it doesn’t show the Uconnect WiFi SSID. But it shows my home WiFi and can connect. My iPhone can connect to Uconnect car wifi. The Uconnect WiFi had WPA2 security and my hobe had WPA2 PSK. Please assist.

Comment: sure you are talking about WiFi (not bluetooth)? 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz channel incompatibility (wrong country)? beacon interval too low?

Comment: Yes I am sure and I am in USA

Comment: Seems like issue with Android go edition. Not sure where to get an answer